# Link Intuit app to Quickbooks company data rather than snadbox data

Tags: php, mysqli, quickbooks

I've been following Keith Palmer tutorial for linking Quickbooks to PHP. I used the sample code (example_app_ipp_v3/index.php) and it all works great.

The problem how I can set up production keys so I can use my actual company data not sandbox data.

In simple words I've got development keys which I used for sandbox data. How shall I go on about syncing company data. Where shell I start form.

Many Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To go, live, you need to:

- Click the PUBLISH button in your Intuit control panel, to get your `production` keys
- Put the production keys in your code
- Make sure you are *not* telling your code you're in `sandbox` mode (search your code for `->sandbox(`
- Click the *CONNECT TO QUICKBOOKS* button to connect your live company